# Simple proof of area of "rectangled" circle

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, circles

Here is a simple problem which I would occasionally assign to my precalculus students and to my calculus students. The precalculus students always found a simpler answer. Sometimes it is possible to know too much. :)

Construct a simple proof that the area of the shaded region of the circle is $$ \frac{1}{2}\pi r^2+2ab $$

[image: Rectangled circle]

Caution! Mousing over the yellow region will reveal the answer.

> [image: Rectangled Circle "Proof"]

Bonus: For those who got the answer or who revealed the answer, what does the dashed line represent? What is its equation?

Comment: That's a neat way to showcase the symmetry. As for the dashed line, my guess would be $\,a\,b=const\,$ i.e. the locus of points which give the same shaded area.

Comment: @dxiv That's correct.

Comment: Too much knowledge can make you think like a robot after a while if you're not careful. In the spider in a cuboid room, I tried to minimize the distance function by setting its derivative equal to zero. More thinking required. http://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-86-shortest-path-cuboid/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: areas]

As a variation on the same symmetry clues used in the posted spoiler, the areas of the white and shaded parts are, respectively:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
S_W &= S' + 2 S'' + S''' \\
S_B &= S'+2 S''+S''' + S
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

Therefore $S_B-S_W=S=4ab$ and since $S_B+S_W=\pi r^2$ the result immediately follows.