# A circle and two perpendicular lines enclose four regions. Can the regions have distinct rational areas?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, number-theory, trigonometry

A circle and two perpendicular lines enclose four regions. Can the regions have distinct rational areas? (I stipulate *distinct* to eliminate trivial cases in which one of both of the perpendicular lines go through the center of the circle.)

My approach was to let the circle be $x^2$+$y^2$=$1/\pi$ (so the area of the circle is one), then let the perpendicular lines be $y=a$ and $x=b$, then express the four areas in terms of $a$ and $b$ and try to show that the areas cannot all be rational. But I quickly got lost in very complicated expressions for the areas.

I've tried to work with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2061575/simple-proof-of-area-of-rectangled-circle/2061650#2061650), but I have come up with nothing.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4317354/inscribe-a-triangle-in-a-circle-to-produce-four-areas-can-the-four-areas-be-int) is another question about four regions in a circle, which has not received any answer yet; I'm not sure if it would help answer my question.

[This resolved question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4318386/a-triangle-has-one-vertex-at-a-circles-center-and-two-vertices-on-the-circle-c) makes me suspect that the answer to my question is no.

Comment: You may assume that the circle is of the form $x^2 + y^2 = R^2$, and the lines are, as you say, $x = a$ and $y = b$. Do you by any chance know closed-form expressions for the four resulting areas in terms of $a$, $b$ and $R$?

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer Yes, but the expressions are overwhelmingly complicated (and they do not seem to simplify), such that I have no hope that those expressions would allow me to answer the question.

Comment: These painful expressions might become quite nice (yielding stuff onlly involving terms like $\sqrt{3}$, $\sqrt{5}$ and $\pi$) if you take say $R = 1$, $x = 1/2$ and $y = 1/3$. After that you can try to scale by an appropriate factor to make all these numbers rational. This is just a guess, though...

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete answer, but maybe someone can build off of it.

---

I'm going to slightly re-parametrize your variables. Let the circle still be $x^2+y^2=\frac{1}{\pi}$, but let the lines be $x=\frac{a}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ and $y=\frac{b}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ (this is just to make the later calculations look nicer). Then also assume that $0 < a < b < 1$.

Then the area of the top-right section is $$\int_{\frac{a}{\sqrt{\pi}}}^{\frac{\sqrt{1-b^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi}-x^2}-\frac{b}{\sqrt{\pi}}\right)dx$$ which is $$t_1=\frac{ab}{\pi}+\frac{\arccos(b)-b\sqrt{1-b^2}}{2\pi}-\frac{\arcsin(a)+a\sqrt{1-a^2}}{2\pi}$$

The area of the bottom-left section is then $t_3=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2ab}{\pi}-t_1$ (using the linked question). Similarly, the top-left section is $$t_2=\frac{\arccos(b)-b\sqrt{1-b^2}}{\pi}-t_1$$

and the bottom-right section is $t_4=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{2ab}{\pi}-t_2$

If $t_1$ is rational, then for $t_3$ to be rational, $r_1=\frac{ab}{\pi}$ must be rational. Also for $t_2$ to be rational, $r_2=\frac{\arccos(b)-b\sqrt{1-b^2}}{\pi}$ must be rational.

So using that $r_1$ and $r_2$ must be rational, that then also means (since $t_1$ must be rational) that $r_3=\frac{\arcsin(a)+a\sqrt{1-a^2}}{\pi}$ must be rational. All the sections can in fact be represented in terms of $r_1, r_2, r_3$. Specifically, $t_1=r_1+\frac{r_2}{2}-\frac{r_3}{2}$, $t_2=-r_1+\frac{r_2}{2}+\frac{r_3}{2}$, $t_3=\frac{1}{2}+r_1-\frac{r_2}{2}+\frac{r_3}{2}$, and $t_4=\frac{1}{2}-r_1-\frac{r_2}{2}-\frac{r_3}{2}$. So it is necessary and sufficient for $r_1, r_2, r_3$ to be rational.

That's as far as I've gotten, and I've tried adding, multiplying and dividing $r_i$ with each other, but with little headway. I think it's true that neither $a$ nor $b$ can be algebraic (nor even algebraic multiples of $\pi$), but I'm not sure about this.