# How can we determine if a question is an open question?

Tags: soft-question

In mathematics, an *open question* is a question that no one has been able to answer. There are incomplete lists of open questions, for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_mathematics#21st_century).

Suppose I think of a question and cannot answer it. I search for it but cannot find it. I post it ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4321006/a-circle-and-two-perpendicular-lines-enclose-four-regions-can-the-regions-have?noredirect=1&lq=1)) and receive no answer. I wonder if it is an open question. How can I determine if it is an open question?

Comment: Try asking on meta Stack exchange?

Comment: @TymaGaidash OK, but how would the posters on meta Stack exchange know if it is an open question?

Comment: @Dan How would anyone know anything? (Sort of serious question. You have to accept some level of verification, otherwise you cannot prove that the Riemann Hypothesis is open, because my dead grandfather had a proof for it but took it to his grave.)

Comment: @Dan Any question that has an answer option is open as long as it is not [closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions). Try to  bump/edit the question or answer it yourself for some question activity. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg OK, so what level of verification is generally accepted?

Comment: @TymaGaidash My question is not intended to be about the mechanics of the stackexchange website; it is about how we know if a question is (or would be) considered to be an open question in general.

Comment: @Dan: Maybe that is the question you should be asking. I am not sure if that is a question for this site though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way of knowing with absolute certainty that a given mathematical problem is still 'open' i.e. to confirm that no-one else has already solved it, since no method of searching for pre-existing solutions is completely foolproof. However, if the problem is now 'closed', then there are number of ways of finding out about it that are likely to succeed.

The first place to look would be [MathSciNet](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet), an online database of research papers in the mathematical sciences that is rather exhaustive and contains over 4 million papers to date. You can do very detailed searches here using [subject classification codes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/classifications/MSC.html) and even search formatted LaTeX terms. You do need a membership of some kind to access this though, which will usually be through your university.

The second place to check would probably be the [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/) (pronounced 'archive'), where mathematicians can upload preprints of papers prior to publication, and also their own notes. This is all freely available, yet there is no requirement that work submitted there is peer reviewed, so in theory anyone could upload their work and some of what is on there is of questionable quality.

Google might throw up something obscure, like an old set of notes from a conference or various blog posts. [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) is of course a good place to ask for references to literature on open problems or anything to do with research-level mathematics. There is a lot in mathematicians' heads that has not been committed to writing and therefore is not publicly available.